# Scanresult is always empty on Android 6.0

Tags: android, wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow, network-scan

I have migrated my app to Android 6.0.
But from in this migration, Wifi Scanresult is always empty.
In some articles, I saw it's related new permission policy for location.
So, I added use-permission `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in the manifast.

Additionally, I added some code `requestPermissions`, `onRequestPermissionsResult` and checked permission is granted successfully. But the scanresult is still empty.

After I enabled location setting manually, it works fine.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Seems you have to enable location to get wifi ScanResult in Android 6.0

you may find more info [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185370)

Comment: you are a life saver